# How to create a simple navigation based application in xcode without storyboard and page-based?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

can any One Give me an example to create simplest navigation based application in xcode 5.1 without use of storyboard and page-based application. I tried so much to find it but every where it is available in  xcode 4. I want to perform this task in single view based application. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Xcode 5.1 ???????????????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution of my own question.
In ios 5.1, use the Master-Detail Application. **Deselect** the check box of storyboards and relative. There will be a simple table view  application ready to use. Modify it as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This Link will help you lot,before you must Deselect the check box of Use storyboards on project creation time

[image]
  http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/iosdev/navigationcontroller/